# Fastest Way to access and put values in matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I wrote a program and have been profiling it. The bottlenecks are the following (if I use a sparse matrix):

```
  26534    0.775    0.000   66.657    0.003 compressed.py:638(__setitem__)
  26534    2.240    0.000   59.438    0.002 compressed.py:688(_set_many)
  13318    2.993    0.000   50.024    0.004 compressed.py:742(_insert_many)
3034231   23.087    0.000   38.101    0.000 defmatrix.py:312(__getitem__)
```

If I use a dense matrix, then these operations are slow (have to init matrix to zeros)

```
3034072   24.902    0.000   41.135    0.000 defmatrix.py:312(__getitem__)
  11780   19.586    0.002   19.586    0.002 {numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
```

The sparse matrix version is faster (193s versus 178s). But retrieving and putting in rows is clearly a bottleneck for me. I tried using the `take` function, where I use `range()` to create an array containing the indices of the row. However that is much worse (by a factor of 10000) than what I am currently doing, which is for matrix X, `X[idx,:]` for putting and `X.getrow(idx).todense()` for taking.

Is there a better way to access and replace these rows? My matrices are quite large (~100000 rows 20-500 cols).

Edit:
I am using csr_matrix (but open to any kind of sparse matrix - this one seemed suited for grabbing rows). Below is a series of tests just to give a MWE. The speeds are about 3E-4s, 7E-3s, .1s. This is surprising to me and I wonder if there is a faster way to do it than the top approach. If I remove the todense() call the sparse time gets cut in half - but this still seems pretty slow.

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def testFancy(mat,idxs):
    for i in idxs:
        x = mat[i,:]

def testTake(mat,idxs):
    for i in idxs:
        x = mat.take(range(i*50,i*50+50))

def testSparse(mat,idxs):
    for i in idxs:
        x = mat.getrow(i).todense()

mat = np.random.rand(50000,50)
idxs = np.random.randint(50000-1, size=1000)

#fancy
t0 = time()
testFancy(mat,idxs)
t1 = time()
print str(t1-t0)

#take
t0 = time()
testTake(mat,idxs)
t1 = time()
print str(t1-t0)

#sparse
mat = csr_matrix((50000,50))
t0 = time()
testSparse(mat,idxs)
t1 = time()
print str(t1-t0)
```

Comment: An [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Comment: Could you provide an minimal working example we could copy-paste ? It's hard to say anything otherwise.

Comment: Also note that there are different implementations of a sparse matrix. From the term `sparse matrix` alone we can only guess the underlying data structure.

Comment: The `sparse.csr_matrix` has a well defined data structure - compressed sparse row.

Comment: Your `csr_matrix((50000,50))` has 0 nonzero elements.  It doesn't makes sense to compare it with a dense array of the shape.  You need to give more details on this ` retrieving and putting in rows` bit.  Also read the pros/cons of the various sparse formats (e.g. compare csr with lil, etc).

Comment: I am sorry if I am unclear. Essentially I have two main choices (without doing anything odd like use a map). I either make a sparse matrix (fast creation) and then modify/access rows. Or I make a dense all zero matrix and add or modify rows. The best solution would be a sparse matrix that has fast access. But this doesn't seem to be the case unfortunately as getrow() is too slow compared to the dense version. Maybe another sparse data structure would be better for this problem?

Comment: The `csr` docs say: `changes to the sparsity structure are expensive (consider LIL or DOK)`.  The underlying data structures for those are lists of lists and a dictionary.

Comment: LIL is also slow. Also around ~0.1s using the same test.

Answer (score 1):

Just use fancy indexing, both for getting and setting rows in an array,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

mat_ds = np.random.rand(50000,50)
mat_csr = csr_matrix((50000,50))
mat_lil = mat_csr.tolil()

idxs = np.random.randint(50000-1, size=1000)

print(mat_sp[idxs, :].todense())
print(mat_csr[idxs, :])

mat_sp[idxs, :] = 2.0 # or any other expression that makes sens here
mat_csr[idxs, :] = 2.0
```

it shouldn't matter if the arrays is sparse or not. This will be faster than any custom solution with a loop (~ 250x faster than `testSparse` in my case).

Of course the assignment to a sparse array should be done in a way to preserve sparsity, or else it will be reallocated, which is costly for `csr_matrix`. For instance the example above, produces the a warning because of it.

**Edit**: in response to the comments. Let's consider querying just one row,

```
In [1]: %timeit -n 1 mat_csr[0, :].todense()
1 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit -n 1 mat_lil[0, :].todense()
1 loops, best of 3: 157 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit -n 1 mat_ds[0, :]
The slowest run took 8.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1 loops, best of 3: 954 ns per loop
```

so yes, querying a dense array, is 10 to 100 times faster then sparse array with the result cast as dense (whether you use csr or lil arrays), because there is less overhead. Nothing could be done about it, you just have to make a choice whether you need sparse arrays or not.

Comment: The loop was just to normalize the time of computation. The accesses will be done one row at a time.

Comment: @user671931 I updated the answer to take into account your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a dok_mat:rix. The result on my test is 0.03s and the overall application is 66s with:

```
3034124   11.833    0.000   20.293    0.000 defmatrix.py:312(__getitem__)
```

This seems to be a nice compromise - but I do wonder if it could be better.